# Why can't I emulate this css style?

Tags: css

I like the 37Signals.com header font, and was trying to figure out what styling they use. In Chrome I grabbed the computed style, and then applied it to my own header- but the fonts are clearly different. How could two elements with the same style render differently in the same browser?

Compare the header font in [37signals.com](http://37signals.com/) and http://jsfiddle.net/gLuxS/

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference. What is different?

Comment: It still looks exactly the same to me. I'm using Chrome as well. Curious. Maybe the Minion Pro isn't loading for me on 37signals for some reason.

Comment: hmm wierd- im on a mac too..?

Comment: Folks are so fast to vote to close lately, with narry a peep.  Kinda rude.

Comment: @Ed- yeah, and always on the popular ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to the Minion Pro fonts? They are using Typekit to include the font file for users.

Comment: Motoxer4533- I see, but doesn't there need to be a Typekit directive in CSS? How does that work?

Comment: You could also use Google Web Fonts which probably has an easier to use API.

Comment: @Derek - Google Web Fonts doesn't have Minion Pro in it's library, which the OP is looking for.

Comment: That is true... then again, if he could find something similar it would be free. From what I could tell, TypeKit has a very limited free account with a "trial library".

Answer (score 2):

You get a [typekit](https://typekit.com/) account and purchase the rights to use the same fonts that are being used by 37signals.

<sub>The only reason I'm saying typekit is because that's what 37signals is using for a font provider</sub>

To use custom fonts you'll need to include the font as part of your css. There are many services that provide hosting for fonts so that you don't have to do the messy work of trying to support finnicky custom-font code.

Answer (score 1):

Your not loading the web font `minion-pro-1`

check out [typekit](https://typekit.com/) or [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/). Get and account and embed the fonts how they say to.